# How to run metro webservice on OSGi + jetty?

Tags: web-services, jetty, osgi, java-metro-framework, apache-felix

I'm trying to get a WebService (wsdl) to work on Jetty using OSGi (Felix) + Metro ?

I got Servlets and JSP's working on OSGi + Jetty, but not a WebService using Metro. I have a sample OSGi WAR file to test, which I deployed on Glashfish and it worked. The same I need to deploy on Jetty.

Please share some samples or instructions on this.

Thank you

Vivek

Answer (score 0):

Neil Bartlett has a project at Git hub, https://github.com/njbartlett/jaxrs-osgi-extender, that might be of interest.